# Turn array into objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, javascript-objects

I'm trying to sort a big collection of data in google sheets app script which doesn't support ES6! (I think)

The array looks something like this
var data = [["Frank", "franck@gmail.com", 21],["Mark", "Mark@gmail.com", 23]]

I would love the idea to turn the array into objects where I can access every object by the name ex:

```
Frank.name
Frank.email
Frank.age
```

I tried the following

```
function Driver(name, email, age) {
    this.name= name;
    this.email= email;
    this.age = age;
  }
```

and then

```
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
  data[i][0]= new Driver (data[i][0],data[i][1],data[i][2])
}
```

But it is not working
Can You help me with this?

Comment: Can the data array be made to an object? Example: var data= {name: 'John Doe', email: 'john@doe.com', age: 35};

Comment: If you get same names, you lose the old value, [["Frank", "franck@gmail.com", 21],["Mark", "Mark@gmail.com", 23], ["Frank", "Frank2@gmail.com", 24]]. So better to convert you array to array of object and iterate them.

Comment: In case, If you want to convert into an array of objects, this might be helpful.

var data = [["Frank","franksmail",2], ["name2", "mail2", 3], ["name3", "mail3", 4]]
var drivers = data.map(props => new Driver(...props))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your requirement

> I would love the idea to turn the array into objects where I can access every object by the name

correctly, then the solution is as simple as this:

**ES6 Version**

```js
function Driver(name, email, age) {
    this.name= name;
    this.email= email;
    this.age = age;
}

const data = [["Frank","franksmail",2], ["name2", "mail2", 3], ["name3", "mail3", 4]]


const mappedData = data
//map the array of arrays to an array of Drivers
.map(props => new Driver(...props))
//reduce the array of drivers to a single object
.reduce((accumulator, currentDriver) => {
    accumulator[currentDriver.name] = currentDriver
    return accumulator
}, {})


console.log(mappedData)
console.log(mappedData.Frank.email)
```

**ES5 Version:**

```js
function Driver(name, email, age) {
    this.name= name;
    this.email= email;
    this.age = age;
}
var data = [["Frank","franksmail",2], ["name2", "mail2", 3], ["name3", "mail3", 4]]


var mappedData = data
//map the array of arrays to an array of Drivers
.map(function (props) {
  return new Driver(props[0], props[1], props[2])
})
//reduce the array of drivers to a single object
.reduce(function (accumulator, currentDriver) {
    accumulator[currentDriver.name] = currentDriver
    return accumulator
}, {})


console.log(mappedData)
console.log(mappedData.Frank.email)
```

**Warning:**
If you have to Divers with the same `name` in your `data` array then you'll loose one of them.

Comment: What if you get the same name in the array, you lose the old value. Better to convert an array of objects.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I am aware of this fact, however the OP might not. (he's asking for the objects to be accessible by their name). I've added a notice

Comment: Yeah, but just to inform 

Comment: @Wendelin Apps Script does not support ES6, hence TheMaster's downvote.

Comment: @TheMaster oh, ok. I'm sorry. I indeed missed out on that detail. But next time please provide more specific comment. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help the code works perfectly. It really made my life easier